# Adding copy right click Context menu to data grid column in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, commandbinding

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="S.No" Binding="{Binding SerialNumberId}"
                                            IsReadOnly="True">

                            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
                                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem Command="Copy"></MenuItem>
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                               </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>  
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I want to add copy option in the context menu of this particular column "S.No" of the data grid. But the content of whole row is getting copied instead of just one cell in the grid. How can I achieve copying of only one cell on which context is applied and not the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

use a CommandParamter for your command like this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Change your Command parameters in your code and you can use it.

Comment: still getting contents of the entire row on copy :(

Comment: change your target type to: TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">

Comment: still the same thing is happening

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CommandBinding on your DataGrid to bind to a function :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" Executed="DatagridExecuted" />
    </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In the function, you can find the source of the event,

get its DataContext that corresponds to a line,

and from the DataContext, get the exact property you can put in the clipboard

```
private void DatagridExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;
    if (cell != null)
    {
        Product product = cell.DataContext as Product;
        if (product != null)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(product.SerialNumberId);
        }
    }
}
```